# Contextual link in Product Display type to allow me to edit the referenced Product?

Tags: commerce, navigation

I have a Product Display node and it has the following contextual links: **Edit**, **Delete** and **Manage Display**.

The **Edit** link allows to edit the Product Display node.  I need to add another contextual link to allow me to edit the product referenced by the product display.

Please take a look a this image:

[image]

Comment: What happens if the product display contains more than one referenced node?

Comment: good question. But in my case it only references one product. Anyway which other options do I have to add this capability.

Answer (score 0):

This is a year old question, but worth answering I think.

You can use this [hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_contextual_links_alter/7) (hook_menu_contextual_links_alter). The sample does exactly what you want. (I mean altering node's contextual links)

Here's an actual code I did. And it works for multiple products too.

```
    // Add a link to all contextual links for nodes of type product_display.
    if ($root_path == 'node/%' && $router_item['page_arguments'][0]->type == 'product_display') {

      // Loop through all products
      foreach ($router_item['page_arguments'][0]->field_product[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $element) {
        $product = commerce_product_load($element['product_id']);  

        // Add your contextual link
        $links['edit_prod_'.$element['product_id']] = array(
          'title' => t('Edit @sku', array('@sku' => $product->sku)),
          'href' => 'admin/commerce/products/'.$element['product_id'].'/edit',
          'localized_options' => array(
            'query' => array(
            'destination' => current_path(),
          ),
        ),
      );      
    }
  }
```

This will add contextual links like 'Edit HMWPB' or 'Edit POHPB'